# VBA: Nested Loop Only Runs Once

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested-loops

```
    srcPath = Dir("M:\UPLOAD\Feedback\*.xlsx")
        
    For Each File In myArray
        currentFile = CStr(File)
                                                                        'MsgBox File
        
        Do While srcPath <> ""
            compareFile = CStr(srcPath)
            If currentFile = compareFile Then
                MsgBox (currentFile & compareFile)
                
            Else: End If
            srcPath = Dir()
        Loop
        MsgBox compareFIle
    Next File
```

I want it to loop through the array (which is a list of filenames), then compare the file name in each index to the files in the srcPath folder. If there is a match, it should print the two files that are being compared.

It works for one file match- the first file in the array list. Then the For loop continues but it never enters the Do While part after the first result.

I've tried other loops but they don't work as well for looping through the folder.

Eventually- I want this macro to take a list of files in Excel, compare the filenames to a folder, if the filename in the list matches the filename in the folder, then I want it to copy the file in that folder to a new location. I thought it would be easy but vba is so finnicky.

Comment: `If Len(Dir("M:\UPLOAD\Feedback\" & currentFile) > 0` will tell you directly whether that file is in the folder.  No need for a nested loop.    BTW you would need to move the first line inside the loop for your posted approach to work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I'm not totally sure why Len() works in this instance for file comparison, though.

Comment: Dir returns a String - so Len is just checking the length of the returned value

Comment: That's what I thought. So what if all the filenames have the same number of characters?

Comment: `Len(myString)>0` only checks to see if `myString` has no value (ie. if it's an empty string).  Once > 0 the actual number of characters doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I understand that len(myString)>0 is checking for empty vs. not empty. What I don't understand is how using len() compares the two filenames to determine a match.

Comment: It doesn't compare two filenames - it only ensures the call to Dir with the exact full path returns a value: if there was no matching file then Dir() would return an empty string.   Eg; `Dir("C:\Temp\existingFile.txt")` returns "existingFile.txt", but `Dir("C:\Temp\nonExistingFile.txt")` returns an empty string.   You could get the same result using `If fso.FileExists("M:\UPLOAD\Feedback\" & currentFile) Then`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fileexists-method

Answer (score 1):

Need to move that first line:

```
For Each File In myArray
    currentFile = CStr(File)
    srcPath = Dir("M:\UPLOAD\Feedback\*.xlsx")
    Do While srcPath <> ""
        compareFile = CStr(srcPath)
        If currentFile = compareFile Then 
            MsgBox (currentFile & compareFile)
        End If
        srcPath = Dir()
    Loop
    MsgBox compareFIle
Next File
```

This is more direct though:

```
Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "M:\UPLOAD\Feedback\"

For Each File In myArray
    If Len(File) > 0 Then                         'not an empty entry  
        If Len(Dir(FOLDER_PATH & File)) > 0 Then  'any matched file?
            Debug.Print "Matched", File
        Else
            Debug.Print "### Not Matched", File 
        End If
    End If
Next File
```

Comment: Thank you for answering both using my logic and something more optimized, this is great. Only one question though: when I use your len() approach, it looks like it might be skipping the last index of the array because the readout shows the second to last line item and then the last output is null or whitespace.

Comment: Are any of you entries in `myArray` empty?  If Yes then maybe add a line to check for that before calling Dir...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. The last filename is not present in the search folder. I will have to build in some kind of conditional for when there isn't a match.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've been agonizing over this because I'm on a deadline and falling behind and this solved it. Love this forum.

Comment: Made a couple of edits above....

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.